# How to create links to MS Teams tabs which can be used from within MSTeams on a page

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

In a MSTeams channel I have a tab which has a sharepoint page added to it.  If it is important the sharepoint page resides within the same sharepoint site set up automatically by MS Teams for this team.

I want to use a sharepoint Quick Links web part to provide a link to another MSTeams channel tab.

Currently I am copying the link to the tab within the MSTeam desktop app. In the sharepoint Quick Link I am then pasting the link in the "From Another Link" choice of the Quick Link link.

This works if you click on these links within the Desktop App and if you use the Web Online version, however it does not work if you use the iOS MS Teams app.

Is there another way to link to channel tabs?  [There is this question and answer but this only applies to the web online application.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54139516/redirection-to-another-tab-from-within-a-tab-fails-in-microsoft-teams)

I see on the MS UserVoice that there is still no way to change the landing page when clicking on a channel. Am I correct? [Here is the link to the UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/18695377-change-which-tab-is-default-landing-page-for-a-tea)

Answer (score 1):

I've been researching into this a bit but I can't find a good answer - I feel like Deeplinking should support this somehow, but I haven't got a clear answer. It's *possible* (but I've not tested it), that you can use standard [Deep Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links?view=msteams-client-js-latest) syntax, but use the App Id and Entity Id that you'd get from the Graph Api (e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-tabs?view=graph-rest-1.0)).

Another possibility is just to use an app that's more geared towards this, like [Quicklinks](https://www.chitchattr.com/quicklinks/) (disclosure: I work on this app).

Comment: So there might indeed be another way, but I can't fully test it. You can use the following graph endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team id}/channels/ and then use the "webUrl" property for the channel. You can use Graph Explorer to easily do this in the browser (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)